# How to return a calculated value using map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dictionary

Hey beginner javascripter  here. I want the return num - 32 * 5 / 9 to do it in order and not in BODMAS. So first take away 32 then multiply by 5 then finally divide by 9. How can i do this on a single line?

```
function convertTemps(array) {
    const mappedNumbers = array.map((num) => {
        return num - 32 * 5 / 9
    })
    return mappedNumbers
}

console.log(convertTemps([23, 140, 212, 41]));
```

Comment: Just use parentheses to prioritize the operations? `return (((num - 32) * 5) / 9)`

Comment: JavaScript always follows BODMAS, there's nothing you can do about that. You just have to remember what the B stands for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a solution to your problem is using parentheses so you can control what part of the equation is solved first:

```
function convertTemps(array) {
    return array.map(num => (num - 32) * 5 / 9);
}

console.log(convertTemps([23, 140, 212, 41]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take parenteses and omit curly brackets.

```js
function convertTemps(array) {
    return array.map(num => (num - 32) * 5 / 9);
}

console.log(convertTemps([23, 140, 212, 41]));
```